# Journal warning at boot

Tags: boot

I have an error message stopping the boot of my system. Message telling me to run journalctl.
Ran journalctl @ command line.  This is a cut out of the output where the warning starts.
Apr 03 17:14:18 inspector-Gazelle-Professional gnome-shell[1722]: [AppIndicatorSupport-WARN] Attempting to re-register :1.61/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/multiload; resetting instead

This message continues to the bottom of the journal page. Any suggestions?
Thanks, Fred

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator/+bug/1739468), as [described here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2398232).

A workaround is to remove `indicator-multiload`, at the command line do:

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-multiload
```

Or use your package manager to remove it.

Comment: Removed from command line: 
I will try reboot and see if this solves problem.  Thanks MUCH! Fred

Comment: On reboot:  -- Logs begin at Wed 2019-04-03 17:14:18 EDT, end at Mon 2019-06-17 21:33:59 EDT. --
Apr 03 17:14:18 inspector-Gazelle-Professional gnome-shell[1722]: [AppIndicatorSupport-WARN] Attempting to re-register :1.61/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/multiload; resetting instead
Apr 03 17:14:18 inspector-Gazelle-Professional gnome-shell[1722]: [AppIndicatorSupport-WARN] Item :1.61/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/multiload is already registered
Continues on as long as I continue paging down. ???? The purge seemed to work not sure why WARN continues. Fred

Comment: You still can't boot? FWIW pastebin.com is a good way to share your log file output. I don't quite understand how you're getting log notices labelled "Apr 03 ...". In theory you could purge all the indicator files, but maybe try `sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-appindicator libayatana-appindicator*`? Or it might be a problem with having such large logs, for which `sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=100M # don't keep more than 100M of journals in total` should help? Do you still have multiload somehow - `ls -al /usr/bin/indicator-multiload` should show nothing there.

Comment: Apr 03 17:14:18 inspector-Gazelle-Professional gnome-shell[1722]: [AppIndicatorSupport-WARN] Attempting to re-register :1.61/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/multiload; resetting instead  Failed to delete archived journal /var/log/journal/c9a86897495748ee96ced18dc00568bf/system@00058b8e2746f16d-0d3b06877c56faed.journal~: Permission denied
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals from /var/log/journal/c9a86897495748ee96ced18dc00568bf.

 journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 3.9G in the file system.

Comment: Rebooted system is running slowly.  Now in recovery.  BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.15.0-52-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1 ran journalctl -xb, Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d1d2422c\x2db3c9\x2d47aa\x2d8783\x2d847a030e4221.device.
Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1943899c\x2d37c3\x2d4878\x2db503\x2d909ad582364d.device.
Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.device.
Failed to start Flush Journal to Persistent Storage. CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: CUT CHARACTERS LIMIT

Comment: After update using Software Updater system rebooted I used journalctl --vacuum-time=5d this is the journal output for last few boots. https://pastebin.com/ZS3iu1CJ Ubuntu journal caused boot fail ?

Comment: There's no mention of appindicator in that output, and you're saying it's now booting. I think you need to make a new question. Give the version number of your Ubuntu install too. Share your dmesg output, also "systemd-analyze critical-chain". Then from desktop check your task manager (eg gnome-system-monitor) or htop/atop to see what's using resources. Aside: what disk is that, ssd?